# How to install windows 8 along side of Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows, ntfs

I brought new dell laptop which is pre-installed of 12.04, I upgraded it to 13.04. I need some work which will be only available in windows OS. So I plan to install Windows OS in my laptop as a second OS (Dual OS System).

Please tell me it is possible to Install Windows 8 on Ubuntu 13.04?
I searched a lot on Google but the question are mostly ubuntu alongside windows are asked often.

Now I partitioned my Disk for Windows(NTFS). I removed the Linux Swap due to create NTFS partition, (Gparted allow more than 4 partition).

Additionally I want to know the partitioned details is first drive is dell utility, second one is OS, third one is Linux data partition and fourth one is NTFS for Windows (Not yet installed just allocated the space for it).

After finding my GUI view of Gparted Window Please suggest to step by step instruction to install windows 8 on Ubuntu.

Please check the image on this link
http://s16.postimg.org/3kw0tvzfp/Gparted.png

Comment: Is this any use? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 0):

I have used a guide from the same site before on dual-booting, though not this particular guide - the guide is also on older versions of Ubuntu (9.04) and Vista, but it´s my best shot http://apcmag.com/how_to_dualboot_vista_with_linux_linux_is_already_installed.htm

Comment: Thanks I will try and get back to you once if i need not reach my goal.